# How do I replace the 'player turn' text into the winning text? (Project Tic-tac-toe Vanilla Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help on displaying the winning text by replacing it on the 'player's turn' text instead of displaying it separately below. I have tried a lot of ways but I can't seem to figure it out. It keeps on displaying below the turn text. Disregard the previous and next button, I haven't put functions on it yet.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```js
const boxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".box"));
const playerDisplay = document.querySelector(".display-player");
const resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");
const announcer = document.querySelector(".announcer");
const prevBtn = document.querySelector("#previous-btn");
const nextBtn = document.querySelector("#next-btn");

let board = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
let currentPlayer = "X";
let isGameActive = true;
let move = 0;
let moveHistory = [];

const PLAYERX_WON = "PLAYERX_WON";
const PLAYERO_WON = "PLAYERO_WON";
const TIE = "TIE";

const winningConditions = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6],
];

function handleResultValidation() {
  let roundWon = false;
  for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    const winCondition = winningConditions[i];
    const a = board[winCondition[0]];
    const b = board[winCondition[1]];
    const c = board[winCondition[2]];
    if (a === "" || b === "" || c === "") {
      continue;
    }
    if (a === b && b === c) {
      roundWon = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (roundWon) {
    announce(currentPlayer === "X" ? PLAYERX_WON : PLAYERO_WON);
    isGameActive = false;
    return;
  }

  if (!board.includes("")) announce(TIE);
}

const announce = (type) => {
  switch (type) {
    case PLAYERO_WON:
      announcer.innerHTML = 'Player <span class="playerO">O</span> Won';
      break;
    case PLAYERX_WON:
      announcer.innerHTML = 'Player <span class="playerX">X</span> Won';
      break;
    case TIE:
      announcer.innerText = "Tie";
  }
  announcer.classList.remove("hide");
};

const isValidAction = (box) => {
  if (box.innerText === "X" || box.innerText === "O") {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};

const updateBoard = (index) => {
  board[index] = currentPlayer;
};

const changePlayer = () => {
  playerDisplay.classList.remove(`player${currentPlayer}`);
  currentPlayer = currentPlayer === "X" ? "O" : "X";
  playerDisplay.innerText = currentPlayer;
  playerDisplay.classList.add(`player${currentPlayer}`);
};

const userAction = (box, index) => {
  if (isValidAction(box) && isGameActive) {
    box.innerText = currentPlayer;
    box.classList.add(`player${currentPlayer}`);
    updateBoard(index);
    handleResultValidation();
    changePlayer();
  }
};

const resetBoard = () => {
  board = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
  isGameActive = true;
  announcer.classList.add("hide");

  if (currentPlayer === "O") {
    changePlayer();
  }

  boxes.forEach((box) => {
    box.innerText = "";
    box.classList.remove("playerX");
    box.classList.remove("playerO");
  });
};

boxes.forEach((box, index) => {
  box.addEventListener("click", () => userAction(box, index));
});

restartBtn.addEventListener("click", resetBoard);
```

```css
:root {
  --maincolor: #564e58;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: var(--maincolor);
  font-family: "Sigmar One", cursive;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 44px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  color: #9a275a;
}



.display {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.container {
  padding: 40px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#board {
  display: flex;
  width: 450px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: var(--maincolor);
  font-size: 150px;
}

/* change color when box is hovered */
.box:hover {
  background-color: lavenderblush;
}

/* draw lines */
div.box#zero,
div.box#one,
div.box#two {
  border-bottom: 3px solid var(--maincolor);
}

div.box#three,
div.box#four,
div.box#five {
  border-bottom: 3px solid var(--maincolor);
}

div.box#zero,
div.box#three,
div.box#six {
  border-right: 3px solid var(--maincolor);
}

div.box#two,
div.box#five,
div.box#eight {
  border-left: 3px solid var(--maincolor);
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: var(--maincolor);
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 200ms transform;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 350px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#previous-btn {
  transition: 200ms transform;
}

#previous-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}

#next-btn {
  transition: 200ms transform;
}

#next-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Tic-tac-toe Challenge</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sigmar+One&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c592409743.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="titles">
        <h1>Tic-tac-toe</h1>
        
      </div>
      <!-- <h3 id="lets-play-text">Let's Play!</h3> -->
      <div class="display">
        Player<span class="display-player playerX"> X</span>'s turn
      </div>
      <div class="display announcer hide"></div>
      <div id="board">
        <div class="box" id="zero"></div>
        <div class="box" id="one"></div>
        <div class="box" id="two"></div>
        <div class="box" id="three"></div>
        <div class="box" id="four"></div>
        <div class="box" id="five"></div>
        <div class="box" id="six"></div>
        <div class="box" id="seven"></div>
        <div class="box" id="eight"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="button">
        <div id="previous-btn"><i class="fas fa-history"></i></div>
        <button id="restartBtn">Restart Game</button>
        <div id="next-btn"><i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js">
      <i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const boxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".box"));
const playerDisplay = document.querySelector(".display-player");
const resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");
const announcer = document.querySelector(".announcer");
const prevBtn = document.querySelector("#previous-btn");
const nextBtn = document.querySelector("#next-btn");
const display = document.querySelectorAll(".display");

let board = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
let currentPlayer = "X";
let isGameActive = true;
let move = 0;
let moveHistory = [];

const PLAYERX_WON = "PLAYERX_WON";
const PLAYERO_WON = "PLAYERO_WON";
const TIE = "TIE";

const winningConditions = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
];

function handleResultValidation() {
    let roundWon = false;
    for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        const winCondition = winningConditions[i];
        const a = board[winCondition[0]];
        const b = board[winCondition[1]];
        const c = board[winCondition[2]];
        if (a === "" || b === "" || c === "") {
            continue;
        }
        if (a === b && b === c) {
            roundWon = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (roundWon) {
        announce(currentPlayer === "X" ? PLAYERX_WON : PLAYERO_WON);
        isGameActive = false;
        return;
    }

    if (!board.includes("")) announce(TIE);
}

const announce = (type) => {
    switch (type) {
        case PLAYERO_WON:
            display[0].innerHTML = 'Player <span class="playerO">O</span> Won';
            break;
        case PLAYERX_WON:
            display[0].innerHTML = 'Player <span class="playerX">X</span> Won';
            break;
        case TIE:
            display[0].innerHTML = "Tie";
    }
    display[0].classList.remove("hide");
};

const isValidAction = (box) => {
    if (box.innerText === "X" || box.innerText === "O") {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};

const updateBoard = (index) => {
    board[index] = currentPlayer;
};

const changePlayer = () => {
    playerDisplay.classList.remove(`player${currentPlayer}`);
    currentPlayer = currentPlayer === "X" ? "O" : "X";
    playerDisplay.innerText = currentPlayer;
    playerDisplay.classList.add(`player${currentPlayer}`);
};

const userAction = (box, index) => {
    if (isValidAction(box) && isGameActive) {
        box.innerText = currentPlayer;
        box.classList.add(`player${currentPlayer}`);
        updateBoard(index);
        handleResultValidation();
        changePlayer();
    }
};

const resetBoard = () => {
    board = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
    isGameActive = true;
    announcer.classList.add("hide");

    if (currentPlayer === "O") {
        changePlayer();
    }

    boxes.forEach((box) => {
        box.innerText = "";
        box.classList.remove("playerX");
        box.classList.remove("playerO");
    });
};

boxes.forEach((box, index) => {
    box.addEventListener("click", () => userAction(box, index));
});

restartBtn.addEventListener("click", resetBoard);
```

```css
:root {
    --maincolor: #564e58;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: var(--maincolor);
    font-family: "Sigmar One", cursive;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 44px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    color: #9a275a;
}

.display {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.container {
    padding: 40px;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#board {
    display: flex;
    width: 450px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.box {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: var(--maincolor);
    font-size: 150px;
}


/* change color when box is hovered */

.box:hover {
    background-color: lavenderblush;
}


/* draw lines */

div.box#zero,
div.box#one,
div.box#two {
    border-bottom: 3px solid var(--maincolor);
}

div.box#three,
div.box#four,
div.box#five {
    border-bottom: 3px solid var(--maincolor);
}

div.box#zero,
div.box#three,
div.box#six {
    border-right: 3px solid var(--maincolor);
}

div.box#two,
div.box#five,
div.box#eight {
    border-left: 3px solid var(--maincolor);
}

button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: var(--maincolor);
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 200ms transform;
}

button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

.button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 350px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#previous-btn {
    transition: 200ms transform;
}

#previous-btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}

#next-btn {
    transition: 200ms transform;
}

#next-btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Tic-tac-toe Challenge</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sigmar+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c592409743.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="titles">
            <h1>Tic-tac-toe</h1>

        </div>
        <!-- <h3 id="lets-play-text">Let's Play!</h3> -->
        <div class="display">
            Player<span class="display-player playerX"> X</span>'s turn
        </div>
        <div class="display announcer hide"></div>
        <div id="board">
            <div class="box" id="zero"></div>
            <div class="box" id="one"></div>
            <div class="box" id="two"></div>
            <div class="box" id="three"></div>
            <div class="box" id="four"></div>
            <div class="box" id="five"></div>
            <div class="box" id="six"></div>
            <div class="box" id="seven"></div>
            <div class="box" id="eight"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="button">
            <div id="previous-btn"><i class="fas fa-history"></i></div>
            <button id="restartBtn">Restart Game</button>
            <div id="next-btn"><i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <script src="index.js">
      <i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i>
    </script> -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Already figured it out withca different approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just small changes to the functions in the JS file.

```js
const boxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.box'));
const resetButton = document.querySelector('#reset');
const announcer = document.querySelector('.announcer');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#previous-btn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#next-btn');
const display = document.querySelector('.display');


let board = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];
let currentPlayer = 'X';
let isGameActive = true;
let move = 0;
let moveHistory = [];

const TIE = 'TIE';
const PlayerWon = 'PlayerWon';

const winningConditions = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6],
];

function handleResultValidation() {
  let roundWon = false;
  for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    const winCondition = winningConditions[i];
    const a = board[winCondition[0]];
    const b = board[winCondition[1]];
    const c = board[winCondition[2]];
    if (a === '' || b === '' || c === '') {
      continue;
    }
    if (a === b && b === c) {
      roundWon = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (roundWon) {
    announce(PlayerWon);
    isGameActive = false;
    return;
  }

  if (!board.includes('')) announce(TIE);
}

const announce = (type) => {
  switch (type) {
    case PlayerWon:
      display.innerText = `Player ${currentPlayer} Won`;
      break;
    case TIE:
      isGameActive = false;
      display.innerText = 'Tie';
  }
};

const isValidAction = (box) => {
  if (box.innerText === 'X' || box.innerText === 'O') {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};

const updateBoard = (index) => {
  board[index] = currentPlayer;
};

const changePlayer = () => {
  currentPlayer == 'X' ? (currentPlayer = 'O') : (currentPlayer = 'X');
  display.innerText = `Player ${currentPlayer}'s turn`;
};

const userAction = (box, index) => {
  if (isValidAction(box) && isGameActive) {
    box.innerText = currentPlayer;
    updateBoard(index);
    handleResultValidation();
    isGameActive ? changePlayer() : '';
  }
};

const resetBoard = () => {
  board = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];
  isGameActive = true;
  currentPlayer = 'X';
  display.innerText = `Player ${currentPlayer}'s turn`;

  boxes.forEach((box) => {
    box.innerText = '';
  });
};

boxes.forEach((box, index) => {
  box.addEventListener('click', () => userAction(box, index));
});

restartBtn.addEventListener('click', resetBoard);
```

```css
:root {
  --maincolor: #564e58;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: var(--maincolor);
  font-family: "Sigmar One", cursive;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 44px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  color: #9a275a;
}

.display {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.container {
  padding: 40px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#board {
  display: flex;
  width: 450px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: var(--maincolor);
  font-size: 150px;
}


/* change color when box is hovered */

.box:hover {
  background-color: lavenderblush;
}


/* draw lines */

div.box#zero,
div.box#one,
div.box#two {
  border-bottom: 3px solid var(--maincolor);
}

div.box#three,
div.box#four,
div.box#five {
  border-bottom: 3px solid var(--maincolor);
}

div.box#zero,
div.box#three,
div.box#six {
  border-right: 3px solid var(--maincolor);
}

div.box#two,
div.box#five,
div.box#eight {
  border-left: 3px solid var(--maincolor);
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: var(--maincolor);
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 200ms transform;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 350px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#previous-btn {
  transition: 200ms transform;
}

#previous-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}

#next-btn {
  transition: 200ms transform;
}

#next-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Tic-tac-toe Challenge</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sigmar+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c592409743.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="titles">
      <h1>Tic-tac-toe</h1>

    </div>
    <!-- <h3 id="lets-play-text">Let's Play!</h3> -->
    <div class="display">
      Player<span class="display-player playerX"> X</span>'s turn
    </div>
    <div id="board">
      <div class="box" id="zero"></div>
      <div class="box" id="one"></div>
      <div class="box" id="two"></div>
      <div class="box" id="three"></div>
      <div class="box" id="four"></div>
      <div class="box" id="five"></div>
      <div class="box" id="six"></div>
      <div class="box" id="seven"></div>
      <div class="box" id="eight"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
      <div id="previous-btn"><i class="fas fa-history"></i></div>
      <button id="restartBtn">Restart Game</button>
      <div id="next-btn"><i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="index.html">
    < i class = "fas fa-redo-alt" > < /i>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```